# How to add margin-top after table page break?

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

[image]

How to add margin-top for this table on the second page(and on all pages after first)? I've already added "margin-top" attribute to <fo:table margin-top="25">, but this is applied only on the first page, but on the second page as it can be seen, margin after page break doesn't work. ( Page number, orange line and 'Card Statement' is <fo:static-content> and I need some space between them and the table continuation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the graphic at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_simple-page-master.

Either decrease the `extent` of the `fo:region-before` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#extent) or increase the `margin-top` of the `fo:region-body`.